# SQLite: testing whether a student skipped an academic year

Tags: sql, sqlite

SQLITE

I have this Schema:

```
student: sid (string)
course: cid (string)
prerequisite: cid (string), precid (string)
record: sid (string), cid (string), quarter (string), year (integer), grade(integer)
```

I need to find all students who has taken a gap year. This means a student was not enrolled in an academic year, but were enrolled at some point before and after that academic year. An academic year consists of the fall (F) quarter of calendar year N and winter (W) and spring (S) quarters of calendar year N + 1. For example: the academic year 2020-2021 consist of F 2020, W 2021, and S 2021.

This is the query I have so far:

```
select sid 
from (select sid,(max(year)-min(year))+1 as diff, count(*) total, max(year), min(year) 
   from (select distinct * 
         from (select  r1.sid, case when r1.quarter in ('W','S') then r1.year+1 
                             else r1.year end as year from record r1
               union all
               select r2.sid,max(r2.year) as year from record r2 group by r2.sid)) 
   group by sid) 
where diff <> total
order by 1;
```

But it gives me not the right results. My results not giving all the students who had a gap year so I know its something to do with how I checked whether or not it skipped an academic year.

Any tip would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression to calculate the academic year.  Then, aggregate and count to see if any are missing:

```
with cy as (
      select distinct sid, 
             year + (case when quarter = 'F' then 0 else -1 end) as academic_year
      from record r
     )
select sid
from cy
group by sid
having count(*) <> max(academic_year) - min(academic_year) + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input however it does not give me the correct results, i think for the case, it should  be when quarter = 'W' OR 'S' but im not sure if i can write it that way.

Comment: also is there a way without using case statements?

Comment: @dante . . . I think that should be `'F'` rather than `'W'`.

Comment: yes it works quite well, however I was wondering if there's a way without using CASE